# how to select last node

Tags: linux, xslt

i have following code:

```
<xsl:variable name="helper"
              select="func:getSer(service)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$helper">
    <xsl:variable name="itName" select="func:cppNamespacePath(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$itName"/>
```

but it gives error that undefined variable "itName"
i have to get last output from for loop. and use it outside the for loop. plz tell me solution
thanks in advance.

Comment: please take more care formatting your questions.

Comment: Q is that can we print variable from the for loop. i.e. variable which stors the last interated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `getSer()` returns a node-set, you can pass the last of it's elements to `cppNamespacePath()` like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="helper"
    select="func:cppNamespacePath( func:getSer(service)[last()] )"/>
```